# Return Array values from PHP Function

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the users from PHP form. PHP Function has to create new users (username, first name & email) with `registeruser($user)`,that is to insert to database.

I was able to insert only one row to database. Could you guide me to insert more than one user
and return all the users.

The new users come from `$array['newuser'].`

```
function newusers() {
    foreach($array['newuser'] as $row) {
            
        $user = new stdClass();
        $user->username  = $row['username'];
        $user->firstname  = $row['firstname'];
        $user->email = $row['email'];
    
        $userreg = registeruser($user);
        return array($userreg)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you are breaking the loop too early - Better do `$userreg[] =registeruser($user);` and `return` that array after the loop

Comment: @Boo. Thank You. It was working when I call after the loop. How should I return all the values

Comment: _...How should I return all the values..._ Like just said before, return `$userreg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you are searching for this answer;here whenever new user comes it will store to an array $userreg[] =registeruser($user); and return that array after the loop

```
function newusers($array_of_new_users) {
        $userreg=array();
        foreach($array_of_new_users as $row) 
        {
                
            $user = new stdClass();
            $user->username  = $row['username'];
            $user->firstname  = $row['firstname'];
            $user->email = $row['email'];
            $userreg[] = registeruser($user);
         }
    return $userreg;
            
    }
```